# TCP and UDP client + server in C++ using boost

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, server, udp

I want to implement a client + server that supports both TCP/UDP protocols. The idea is that the same program will be run on two machines and they should be able to communicate with each other. Is it traditional to create one class for client and one class for server (for each protocols - hence 4 classes in total) and instantiate a client object and server object in the main? Or is it a good design practice to create one class that implements the functionality of both client and server. What is the commonly accepted practice.[boost examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) shows one class being implemented for each client and server.

Comment: you need different TCP client and server classes, but the UDP classes could  be the same. The comms code in [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib) supports both TCP and UDP protocols, is based upon boost asio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP/UDP protocols can be abstracted by another set of classes (can be called Channel, Stream, Protocol etc.). Then you'd have Client class and Server class, and each of them can use either of TcpChannel and UdpChannel (or both and choose between them at runtime). This is how I have seen this implemented. The Channel can then provide both read and write methods used by both Server and Client.

Comment: Well, that was in a proprietary closed source code, but in the principle it is not that hard. The base class just provides pure virtual read/write methods (or anything else necessary), which are then implemented in the TCP and UDP implementations appropriately. The higher level implementation can then hold pointer to either one of them depending on the setup and use both in an uniform way.